# Python 2.7 Unicode/IDLE confusion

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, python-idle

I've read a lot about Unicode and the various encodings/decodings in Python 2.7, but I'm still having trouble understanding why IDLE can't seem to print the right string.

I have a unicode string:

```
>>> s = u"Hey I\u2019m Bob"
>>> print s
Hey I'm Bob
```

However, after I encode into UTF-8, I get:

```
>>> s.encode('utf-8')
'Hey I\xe2\x80\x99m Bob'
>>> print s.encode('utf-8')
Hey Iâ€™m Bob
```

I can't figure out why I can't print this correctly, but I can write s.encode('utf-8') to a text file and it comes out correctly. Not sure if this has something to do with IDLE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because IDLE's output window isn't supporting UTF-8, but printing a Unicode string automatically tries to encode the string in the stdout encoding.  The following is from an IDLE console:

```
>>> s = u"Hey I\u2019m Bob"
>>> print s
Hey I’m Bob
>>> print s.encode('utf8')
Hey Iâ€™m Bob
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'cp1252'
>>> print s.encode('cp1252')
Hey I’m Bob
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to get IDLE to support UTF-8?

Comment: Not sure.  I use PythonWin from the [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/) extension, which does support UTF-8.

Comment: If you print Unicode strings in IDLE, even though the stdout encoding is `cp1252` (an encoding that doesn't support Chinese), I was able to print Chinese correctly.  So just print Unicode strings without encoding.